# WPA2 Enterprise TTLS PAP connection for iPad

Tags: ipad, wifi

I can't connect to my university's enterprise wireless using my iPad. It uses WPA2 Enterprise with TTLS and PAP. When I enter my username and password it asks me to accept a certificate which is not verified, when I click accept it tells me that the username or password is incorrect (though they are correct). What should I do to fix this?

Comment: With WPA2 Enterprise we had problems if we didn't use full usernames: *username@domain.tld* instead of just *username*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay so I figured it out myself. Apple provides a configuration utility for configuring WiFi and some other settings.

For Windows - http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1466

For Mac - http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1465

I created a configuration profile using it and entered the WiFi settings there -

Security Type - WPA/WPA2 Enterprise

*Protocols*

EAP Types - TTLS

Inner Identity - PAP

*Authentication*

Username - yourusername

Password - yourpassword

I then emailed this configuration profile to myself and opened it from my iPad and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

@Vlad is correct. Alternatively, it may require you to use this format for the username:

domain\username